# Ruby function with an if statement

Tags: ruby

I have this following function but somehow it doesn't get inside the if statement. This is my [gist](https://gist.github.com/guinslym/8590687) on line 68

I'm trying to evaluate if an object.country name has the same name as "example_of_a_country_name"

```
def find_population_of_country(liste_pays, country_name)
  given_country_population = 0
  liste_pays.each do |n| 
    if (n.country.eql?(country_name.upcase))
      given_country_population = n.population

      #I'm trying to see if it's output something here
      puts country_name.upcase
    end
  return given_country_population
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

can you type this within your function and tell me what you get?:

```
def find_population_of_country(liste_pays, country_name)
  liste_pays.select {|n| n.country.eql?(country_name.upcase) }
 end
end
```

Comment: It would also help if you could specify how the models are related.

Comment: thks Sherwyn goh! First now this function works. I'll be able to continue. Second: It's not a model.  I'm trying to learn classes in Ruby by redoing all the assigment that I had in Java. Thks!

Comment: ahh right, my bad didn't see the lack of a 'rails' tag. Happy it works, have fun coding.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your line:

```
return given_country_population
```

This should be moved one line up, inside the `if ... end` block for the name comparison, otherwise, it's returning even for non-matches.

Comment: thks @jeremycole! I was thinking how .select works but not .each ??? thanks for the tip.